# Opening Port 3283 in Cyberoam Firewall to allow Apple Remote Desktop

Tags: firewall

I am fairly new to networking. I would like to open port 3282 in Cyberoam firewall to allow Apple remote desktop.

Is the source port and destination port the same?

How do I create a firewall rule to allow this through?

[image: Add Service]

[Apple TCP/UDP ports](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202944)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface gives you this option to fill in both source and destination to be flexible, but that doesn't mean that they are both required to be filled in. The destination port is the only one that should be set to 3283, whereas the source port should be set to 'any'. I have never worked with a Cyberoam firewall before, but generally leaving that field blank will set it to 'any' with these types of interfaces.